# Jenkins shell command wait for docker container downloaded , up , running

Tags: shell, jenkins, docker

I'm using Docker steps as below to bring up selenium grid

My query is how to gracefully wait till particular container is downloaded , up and running.

```
docker run -ti -m 150M --memory-swap 300M --cpu-shares=104 -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub -e GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=15000 selenium/hub
sleep 10

for i in {1..2}
 do
    echo &quot;Starting Node: $i&quot;
    docker run -ti -m 750M --memory-swap 900M --cpu-shares=460 -d --link selenium-hub:hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-chrome
    sleep 5
done
```

Is there better way of avoiding sleep , as sometimes container download takes longer.

After the job is done , I stop and remove all the containers in order to do fresh start for new job.

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram

Comment: Use `&&` in-between two runs all in one line? `docker run ... && docker run ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the selenium service with **curl** and check the result:

Then in a **while** check for COUNT value if it is different from zero

```bash
COUNT=$(curl -q localhost:4444 | grep 403 | wc -l)
while [ $COUNT -eq 0 ]
do
    sleep 1
    COUNT=$(curl -q localhost:4444 | grep 403 | wc -l)
done
```

Regards

Comment: sorry I didn't understand grep 403 ? Each of the node containers will have unique port , how is 403 related then ?

Comment: When you call the grid via localhost:4444 in the case of a standalone container like selenium/standalone-firefox it returns "Error 403 Forbidden for Proxy" so you can check for it. You can also call http://localhost:4444/grid/console and check in the html with grep how many nodes are registered